# Show error for unsupported custom attribute

Tags: android, xml, error-reporting

I am working on an [Android Library](https://github.com/DamanSingh4321/Amazing-Buttons), which makes buttons of different shapes. The Button's XML looks like this:

```
<com.singh.daman.mybutton.ShapedButton
        android:id="@+id/round"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fill_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:button_type="round_rectangle"
        app:stroke_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:stroke_width="12sp"
        app:text="Round Rectangle"
        app:text_size="16sp"
        app:text_color="#ffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null" />
```

In which attribute `app:button_type="round_rectangle"` have different values like rectangle, star, circle and round rectangle.

The type `round_rectangle` is supported by only Lollipop and Above android versions.

So, When the library user sets `button_type` to `round_rectangle` and the app minimum android version is less than Lollipop, I want to show an error that it is only supported by api 21 and above, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom lint rule. I've never done this, but there are writeups from Google on the topic.
http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules